# Using lua code to obtain rules of different lengths

Tags: luatex

I started to learning LuaLateX nowadays and I'd like to get some rules with increasing lengths, but I can't figure out why this simple code doesn't give the desired output:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luatex,pgffor, luacode, calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myrules}{
    \dimen0=2cm
    \luaexec{
      for i=1,4 do
      tex.dimen[0]=tex.dimen[0]*i
      tex.print("\\color{red}\\rule{\\dimen0}{3pt}\\par")
      end
       }
   }
\myrules
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\luaexec` is a wrapper for`\directlua`. It executes the Lua code and expands to:

```
\color{red}\rule{\dimen0}{3pt}\par
\color{red}\rule{\dimen0}{3pt}\par
\color{red}\rule{\dimen0}{3pt}\par
\color{red}\rule{\dimen0}{3pt}\par
```

Also `\luaexec` calls `\directlua` inside a group. Thus the local assignments of `tex.dimen[0]` are lost before TeX proceeds with the expansion result of `\directlua`.

If the rules should be `2cm`, `4cm`, `6cm`, and `8cm`, then there is also a flaw in the algorithm that yields `2cm`, `4cm`, `12cm`, `48cm`.

Example file for the first version:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luatex,pgffor, luacode, calc}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myrules}{%
    \dimen0=2cm %
    \luaexec{
      for i=1,4 do
        tex.print("\\color{red}\\rule{", tex.dimen[0]*i, "sp}{3pt}\\par")
      end
   }%
}
\myrules
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]